# Rspec + Factory Girl First Example works, 2nd+ do not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, factory-bot

I have an spec like so:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe IncomingMailsController do

  include Devise::TestHelpers

  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory.create(:user)
    @user1 = Factory.create(:user)
    @group = Factory(:group)
    @perm1 = Factory.create(:permission, :user => @user)
    @perm2 = Factory.create(:permission, :user => @user1)
  end

  it "xxxxx case 1" do
   ....
  end

  it "xxxxx case 2" do
   ....
  end
```

The first case 1, works fine but then the 2nd fails with:

```
Failure/Error: @perm1 = Factory.create(:permission, :user => @user)
     RuntimeError:
       Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
     # ./spec/factories.rb:23
```

Does the before each run fresh for each it block?

**factories.rb looks like:**

```
require 'factory_girl'

Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.sequence(:fname) { |n| "fname#{n}" }
  f.sequence(:lname) { |n| "lname#{n}" }
  f.sequence(:email) { |n| "email#{n}@google.com" }
  f.password               "password"
  f.password_confirmation { |u| u.password }
  f.invitation_code        "dmbsrv82811"
end

Factory.define :group do |f|
  f.name "myGroup"
  f.sequence(:private_email) { |n| "myGroup#{n}" }
end

Factory.define :permission do |f|
  f.role_id         1
  f.group_id do
    (Group.find_by_name('myGroup')).id
  end
  f.creator_id do
    (User.find_by_fname('fname1')).id
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: What version of FactoryGirl is this for? Has the FactoryGirl API changed drastically since this post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On line 23 of factories.rb you have

```
(User.find_by_fname('fname1')).id
```

This is hardcoded to find `fname1`. However, your factory uses a sequence to define fname:

```
f.sequence(:fname) { |n| "fname#{n}" }
```

This means that in the second spec, the value for fname will be fname2, not fname1. This is because sequences aren't reset between different specs.

All of this means that when you call User.find_by_fname, it can't find a user with fname1 (only fname2), so it returns nil, which is why you get the called id for nil error.

-- Edit --

Are you doing anything with the user attribute you pass in to the permission factory (for eg with `Factory.create(:permission, :user => @user)`)? If not, I'd change it to something like

```
Factory.create(:permission, :creator => @user)
```

Note: if you don't have Permission#creator setup as an association with User you'll need to rather do

```
Factory.create(:permission, :creator_id => @user.id)
```

On a similar vein, you might want to define your factory more along the lines of

```
Factory.define :permission do |f|
  f.role_id         1
  f.association :group, :factory => :group
  f.association :creator, :factory => :user
end
```

If your associations are setup correctly, there's no need to worry about the ids, the association does the Right Thing for you.

Comment: Thanks luke. How can I set creator_id based on what the User factory is?

Comment: Something like   f.creator_id    Factory(:user).id ?

Comment: I've replied in the answer above as it's easier to format text there than in these comments :)